Are artificial lights at night bad for Venus flytraps?
I am growing a Venus flytrap (Dionaea muscipula) on a porch. During daytime, the plant receives strong sunlight. When it gets dark, an 800 lumens warm white LED light bulb illuminates the porch. This Venus flytrap therefore experiences very little darkness. Can Venus flytraps remain healthy if they are not given enough darkness?

Although plants can adapt to 24 hrs of light, it's not the ideal scenerio. Plants need the dark cycle to develop correctly.

OTOH, 800 lumens of light over the area of a porch is not much - about the same as a 60 watt incandescent / 10 watt LED bulb.   I'm not at all sure that a plant would care that much about this quantity of light.

Yeah I don't know what the level of lighting is before a plant switches from day mode to light mode. It probably correlates to their light levels in their endemic habitat. Since venus flytraps is part of the jungle undergrowth I suspect that light level is VERY low.

Yes, using artificial lights at night can be bad for Venus flytraps. They need a period of darkness to rest and go through their natural processes. If they are exposed to light at night, it can disrupt their growth and overall health. It’s best to provide them with a consistent light and dark cycle, mimicking their natural environment.
